# Modeling users and groups in tables of DB

Tags: database-design

I am new to the world of data modeling, so this maybe a silly question. I have been modeling a website database and wanted to model `users` of the website. The users fall into 3 groups (each group has different accesses and allowed to see different portions of the website as well as their individual profile pages changes to allow different information to be shown and/or edited):

1. Visiting users
2. Admin users
3. Paying users

Now I could just create 3 different tables but thought that was rather the incorrect option. So I created a single `user` table, but am unsure of how to show which user is of what group.

Hence, I thought of creating a second table `group` and making a 1-to-1 mapping with the user table to show which group the user belongs to.

Is this the correct way of doing this, or is there some better method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a user table with a foreign key to the group table is definitely a great way to model your situation.

```
create table Users
(
    userID int,
    groupID int,
    userName nvarchar(100)
)

create table Groups
(
    groupID int,
    groupName nvarchar(100)
)
```